# Unable to receive props to dump component

Tags: react-native, jsx

I tried all possible ways to get a simple parameter on file `MembershipCard.js`. My Home component `Home.js` simply passes props to `MembershipList.js` where I have done minor Array operations and iterate it to prepare a list. Each item from the list is then pass on to third file `MembershipCard.js`. I'm getting `membership` object in this file and able to prepare a card list at Home page. On Home page I have to show a side line whereas I don't want this side line on other pages (which are also accessing `MembershipCard.js`) hence I'm trying to send a variable on which I will conditionally show side line.

But after so many try out I'm still receiving `undefined`

This is my React component - Home.js

```js
  render () {

    return (

      <Surface>

        <GreetingCard profile={this.props.profile.Profile}/>

        <MembershipList props={this.props}/>

      </Surface>

      )
  }
```

MembershipList.js - this contain only few functions

```js
renderMembershipCard = (membership, i, props, sideLine = true) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity key={i} style={styles.membership} onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Item', { title: membership.gym_name })}>
            {/* <MembershipCard {...{membership, sideLine }}/> */}
            <MembershipCard {...membership} sideLine={sideLine}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

const MembershipList = (props) => {
    let membership = props.props.profile.Membership
    let listArray = [];
    Object.keys(membership).forEach(key => listArray.push(this.renderMembershipCard(membership[key], key, props.props)));
    return (        
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.ListTitle}>Active Membership ({listArray.length})</Text> 
            {listArray}
        </View>
    );
}
```

MembershipCard.js - this file is part of my presentation layer. It only return a Card design.

```js
const MembershipCard = ({membership,sideLine}) => {
console.log('sideLine', sideLine);  // showing undefined
console.log('membership', membership);
return (
        
    <Card>
      <Text style={styles.gymTitleText}>{membership.name}</Text>
      ... JSX code
    </Card>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using simple trik.

Instead of calling it as a component -

`<MembershipCard {...membership} sideLine={sideLine}/>`

call it as a simple JS function using curly braces {} -

`{ MembershipCard (membership, sideLine) }`

This way I can easily pass as many parameters and can easily access all those in called function.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes to your code and it should work. Change props.props seems to be incorrect way of passing props. Use spread operator for passing all props to children in correct manner.

```
<MembershipList {...this.props}/>

const MembershipList = (props) => {
let membership = props.profile.Membership
let listArray = [];
Object.keys(membership).forEach(key => listArray.push(this.renderMembershipCard(membership[key], key, props)));
return (        
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.ListTitle}>Active Membership ({listArray.length})</Text> 
        {listArray}
    </View>
)}

<MembershipCard membership={membership} sideLine={sideLine}/>
```

Comment: Hi Shubham, problem is not at MembershipList.js. This is working fine I'm able to render list on Home page. Problem is at MembershipCard.js where I'm not getting 'sideLine'. And sideLine is just bool value.